# How to randomly select values from array based on starting letter from url

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array named items that has 10 url label values.

I have a function which selects 5 values randomly from the array.

I want to make the selection in such a way that the `URL starts with first letter w or d`

I.E. each item I print to the console should have the `url jpej names` `starting with either w or d`

How can I achieve this?

```js
var array2 = [];

var items = [
  {label: 'crow',
   url: 'wcrow.jpg'},
  {label: 'donkey',
    url: 'ddonkey.jpg'},
  {label: 'lion',
  url: 'wlion.jpg'},
  {label: 'dcat',
   url: 'dcat.jpg'},
  {label: 'cheetah',
    url: 'wcheetah.jpg'},
  {label: 'cow',
    url: 'dcow.jpg'},
  {label: 'dog',
    url: 'ddog.jpg'},
  {label: 'horse',
    url: 'dhorse.jpg'},
  {label: 'rabbit',
    url: 'drabbit.jpg'},
  {label: 'elephant',
    url: 'welephant.jpg'},
  {label: 'rose',},
  {label: 'lotus',
    url: 'flotus.jpg'},
  {label: 'jasmine',
    url: 'fjasmine.jpg'},
  {label: 'snake',
    url: 'rsnake.jpg'},
  {label: 'crocodile',
    url: 'rcrocodile.jpg'}];

array2 = items.slice();

function nameselect() {
  for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);


    console.log(item);
  }

}

nameselect();
```

Comment: @certainperformance  thanks for pointing out ...tag corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `filter` the array by its `url` before selecting the random index. One option is

```
const itemsWithWOrD = items.filter(({ url }) => /^[wd]/i.test(url));
```

Then, in the loop, make sure to declare your variables with `const`, `let`, or `var` to avoid implicitly creating a global variable:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
  const [item] = itemsWithWOrD.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  console.log(item);
}
```

If you don't like regular expressions, an alternative is to use two `startsWith`s:

```
const itemsWithWOrD = items.filter(({ url }) => url && (url.startsWith('w') || url.startsWith('d')));
```

```js
var array2 = [];

var items = [{
    label: 'crow',
    url: 'wcrow.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'donkey',
    url: 'ddonkey.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'lion',
    url: 'wlion.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'dcat',
    url: 'dcat.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'cheetah',
    url: 'wcheetah.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'cow',
    url: 'dcow.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'dog',
    url: 'ddog.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'horse',
    url: 'dhorse.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'rabbit',
    url: 'drabbit.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'elephant',
    url: 'welephant.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'rose',
  },
  {
    label: 'lotus',
    url: 'flotus.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'jasmine',
    url: 'fjasmine.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'snake',
    url: 'rsnake.jpg'
  },
  {
    label: 'crocodile',
    url: 'rcrocodile.jpg'
  }
];

function nameselect() {
  const itemsWithWOrD = items.filter(({ url }) => /^[wd]/i.test(url));
  for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
    const [item] = itemsWithWOrD.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    console.log(item);
  }
}

nameselect();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also have your `startLetters` in an separate array and pass it to your random picker function. You could also pass the number of items you want and then do the filtering via `Array.filter` and `Array.includes` to get your results:

```js
var items = [{ label: 'crow', url: 'wcrow.jpg' }, { label: 'donkey', url: 'ddonkey.jpg' }, { label: 'lion', url: 'wlion.jpg' }, { label: 'dcat', url: 'dcat.jpg' }, { label: 'cheetah', url: 'wcheetah.jpg' }, { label: 'cow', url: 'dcow.jpg' }, { label: 'dog', url: 'ddog.jpg' }, { label: 'horse', url: 'dhorse.jpg' }, { label: 'rabbit', url: 'drabbit.jpg' }, { label: 'elephant', url: 'welephant.jpg' }, { label: 'rose', }, { label: 'lotus', url: 'flotus.jpg' }, { label: 'jasmine', url: 'fjasmine.jpg' }, { label: 'snake', url: 'rsnake.jpg' }, { label: 'crocodile', url: 'rcrocodile.jpg' } ];

const getRandomUrls = (arr, startLetters, num) => {
  let urls = items.filter(({url}) => url && startLetters.includes(url[0]));
  return [...Array(num)].map(x => urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)])
}

console.log(getRandomUrls(items, ['w', 'd'], 5))
```